# Web.config location tag stops working when deployed to Server

Tags: asp.net, web-config, location

Many thanks in advance.  When running the ASP.NET Development Server, everything is working fine.  However, when I deploy my asp.net application to the production server (IIS 7.0 integrated mode, fresh install), my location tags in my web.config file are being ignored.

Case in point: I'm using forms authentication, and when the user arrives at my login.aspx page, the external css & js files are not being loaded...even though I have specified that those files should be available to all users (auth'd or not).  **However, once the user is logged in, the files do in fact load.**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" /> <!-- Restrict anonymouse user access -->
</authorization>
```

And the exception to my css file...

```
  <location path="Styles/xtools.css">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

I've verified that the path to the css file is accurate.  Any suggestions?

Thanks, --Dan

--EDIT
Forgot to mention, I have tried creating a web.config file in the targetted folder as well...still not working.

Comment: Does the Machine Account that IIS is using have security rights on the folder with the CSS and JS files.  The ASP.NET development server runs under the current user account which, for developers, almost always has rights to everything on the box it is running on.  The user account IIS uses (since it using forms authentication, you are not using Active Directory or Machine Accounts to run under) is generally fairly restricted and may need to be granted access to the folders.

Comment: Wouldn't that stop the files from loading even after the user is logged in? -- The files do load after the user has logged in.  (sorry, forgot to mention that, editting post to reflect)

Comment: Update -- those folders did in fact have IIS_USRS group/username with full control in their security tab.  still not working.

Comment: I think you should try give access to Anonymous account IUSR as well. Check this: http://forums.iis.net/p/1173012/1961218.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just got it.  It wasn't enough to give IIS_IUSRS permissions on the folders containing the app ...I needed to give IUSR permissions, as well.

Problem solved.  Thanks, ben f!